# Why sometime we use -> void for completion handler in swift but sometime not?

Tags: swift

I have watched two tutorial. The first one is about basic completion handler in swift. The tutor shows example of this code:

```
func isTextValid(input: String, completion: (result: Bool) -> Void) {

    if (input == "Hello") {
        completion(result: true)
    }else{
        completion(result:false)
    }
}


isTextValid("Hello", { (result) -> Void in
    if (result == true) {
        println("People say Hello")
    }else{
        println("People do not say hello")
    }
})
```

The second tutorial is about HTTP request the code looks like this:

```
        /* 4. Make the request */
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {data, response, downloadError in

        if let error = downloadError {
            println("Could not complete the request \(error)")
        } else {

            /* 5. Parse the data */                
            var parsingError: NSError? = nil
            let parsedResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &parsingError) as! NSDictionary

            /* 6. Use the data! */                
            if let error = parsingError {
                println(error)
            } else {
                if let results = parsedResult["results"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                    self.movies = Movie.moviesFromResults(results)
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } else {
                    println("Could not find results in \(parsedResult)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* 7. Start the request */
    task.resume()
```

You can see that the first line of code doesn't have return void like in the first tutorial, why?

what is return void anyway? why we have to type return void?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of void is optional the same way you can declare a function with or without void you can declare a completion handler with or wihtout

```
func noReturn() -> Void
```

is identical to

```
func noReturn()
```

For completion handles when declaring it:

```
func isTextValid(input: String, completion: (result: Bool) -> Void)
```

is equals to

```
func isTextValid(input: String, completion: (result: Bool) -> ())
```

For completion handles when calling it:

```
(result) -> Void in
```

is equals to

```
(result) in
```

Comment: when I use it I can just type: let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {data, response, downloadError in .........

right?

can I also declare it like this? : func isTextValid(input: String, completion: (result: Bool))  

because from your example I can do this in normal function: func noReturn()

Comment: No when you declare you can omit the word void but you still need the parentheses (result: Bool)->())